# asp.net not showing checked and unchecked in check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

Why is the check and unchecked not working in asp.net, it almost like the property checked is not showing?
I'm trying to use jquery to get the check and unchecked boolean in to an alert?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">



    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>





$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#CheckBox1").click(function () {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           alert("true");

        } else {
            alert("false");
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Firebug to check the ID of the element. I know that ASP.NET will append a random ID string to the end of your CheckBox1 and therefore Jquery would not pick it up.

The best approach would be to surround it by standard HTML and call the element from the parent.

```
<div id="CheckContainer">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

and then

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#CheckContainer input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       alert("true");

    } else {
        alert("false");
    }

});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

The *client side* `ID` of the checkbox will not be `CheckBox1`.

You need to use `CheckBox1.ClientID` to get that and use it in jQuery.

```
$("#<%:CheckBox1.ClientID%>")
```

See [`Control.ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) on MSDN for details.

Comment: but it is  here is the rendered code - <input id="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="CheckBox1" />

Comment: If you view source, or use FireBug, you will see that the ID has taken on the name of the container - container_checkbox1

Answer (score 1):

Because Asp.Net controls have runat="server" attribute the id of the elements will be appended with the ContentPanel .. So the director selector will not work.. try this

So valid Selectors in this case would be

```
$("[id$=CheckBox1]")  
$("[id*=CheckBox1]")
$("#<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>")


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id$=CheckBox1]").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           alert("true");
        } else {
            alert("false");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line and try again

```
<script src="JScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and put your jQuery code inside script Tag. Hope it should work.